# How can I force all maximisable windows to open maximised?

Tags: window-management

Usually I work with all my windows being maximised except for those that cannot be maximised (e.g. calculator).

Is it possible to tweak the behaviour as such that all maximisable windows always open maximised?

Comment: maybe `devilspie` will solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do it in one click, but it is possible in most of the applications to edit the `.desktop` file (located mostly in the `/usr/share/applications`) and edit their commands. It could be a bit time consuming to make it work, but it should be possible in theory. I'll try to find a way to automate the task using bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows can be forced to open maximised using [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/manual.php).

1. Install it: `$ sudo apt-get install devilspie2`
2. Create the config file: `~/.config/devilspie2/open-apps-maximised.lua`
3. Run `devilspie2` from the command-line and add it to the list of applications to run on startup.

Example content of `open-apps-maximised.lua`:

```
if (get_window_role()=="pop-up") then
    maximize();
end

if (get_window_name()=="Messenger") then
    maximize();
end

if (get_window_name()=="WhatsApp Web") then
    maximize();
end
```